# what is wrong with the shell script that i've written

Tags: shell, unix, awk, ksh

Here is the shell script that I've written.

```
file_sequence=998
while [ $file_sequence -ne 000 ]
do
  file_sequence=`printf {"%03d\n",$((file_sequence + 1))}`;
  if [ $file_sequence -gt 999 ]
    then
    file_sequence=`printf {"%03d\n",1}`;
 fi
done
```

The problem here is i'm getting the below output

```
999
001
002
003
upto ..... 009 and then
010
009
010
009
```

Can someone please tell what is happening here.? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your script works fine for me, although I had  to add an `echo $file_sequence` just before the `done` statement to actually see any output. Have you left any part of your script out? Do you have the line `#!/bin/ksh` at the top of your script?

Comment: Hi, try this file_sequence=010 now try executing this file_sequence=`printf {"%03d\n",$((file_sequence + 1))}`; U will get 009 and not 011 :)

Comment: If you run `ksh` before you type those commands you will get 011. If your default shell is not `ksh` and you type those commands then you will get 009. My default shell is `bash` and typing those commands causes the incorrect results but if I run `ksh` first then I get the proper result.

Comment: Compare the outputs from `echo $((10))`, `echo $((010))`, and `echo $((10#010))` and you'll see the problem. Hint: octal. (Those commands are for bash, I don't know if ksh supports the base prefixing. But given some of the other comments you aren't actually using ksh if you have this problem in the first place.)

Comment: The `then` part needlessly calls `printf` to do a static assignment. Just say `file_sequence=001`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's the problem but I do know a way around.

Try this:

```
file_sequence=998
while [ $file_sequence -ne 000 ]
do
  file_sequence=$(printf {"%03d\n",$(bc <<< "$file_sequence + 1")});
  if [ $file_sequence -gt 999 ]
    then
    file_sequence=$(printf {"%03d\n",1});
 fi
   echo "$file_sequence"
done
```

execution:

```
bash script.sh  | head -15
999
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
010
011
012
013
014
```

Comment: The asker is trying to use `ksh`.

Comment: Hi Tiago, I tried your suggestion with #!/bin/ksh and it is working fine. So this script should be ok rite.?

Comment: Hi Tiago, Just had a doubt also, as William Pursell has suggested how did you manage to overcome the octal part in this code can you please explain.? Just wanted to understand how it works. Thanks

Comment: I overcame with `$(bc <<< "$file_sequence + 1")` As I said I didn't know why it wasn't working, it's good to know that was because it treats as octal :)  BTW bc is a command line calculator you will probably use if you want to calculations involving floats.

Answer (score 3):

Integers that begin with `0` are treated as octal.  `010` in octal is `8` in decimal.  8 + 1 is 9.  I think a cleaner solution is to use a variable that tracks the index and a separate variable that worries about formatting:

```
#!/bin/sh

i=998
while test "$i" -ne 0
do
  test $((++i)) -gt 999 && i=1
  file_sequence=$(printf "%03d" $i)
  echo $file_sequence
done
```

Comment: +1 Spot on! This should be the accepted answer. Perhaps supply a simpler workaround than `bc`? I'm thinking base notation if that is available in `ksh`, or simply trimming any leading zeros from the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using file_sequence in combination with another line you want to log.
Your current script would run forever.
Currently you are converting file_sequence between string and integer all the time, causing the problem. Make a log function for the counting:

```
#!/bin/ksh
function my_log
{
  (( file_sequence_nr = file_sequence_nr + 1 ))
  if [ ${file_sequence_nr} -gt 999 ]
  then
    file_sequence_nr=1
  fi
  printf "%03d %s\n" ${file_sequence_nr} "$*"

done

export file_sequence_nr=998
# Loop input file, here a test until 20
while [ $file_sequence_nr -ne 20 ]
do
  my_log "Logline random $RANDOM"
  sleep 1 # Always have a sleep 1 in a while loop until you are sure it works.
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your script to force the script to run using `ksh`:

```
#!/bin/ksh
```